# Безопасно ли выдавать ответы на front-end с именами полей таблиц базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, безопасность

Допустим у нас есть таблица users в базе данных. Она имеет такую структуру:

|user_id|user_name|user_password|user_email|user_phone_number|

При запросе, например SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 1 или при запросе laravel query builder $User->where('user_id' , '=' , 1)->get();

Нам придёт такой ответ:

```
[
    user_id => '1', 
    user_name => 'Vasya' 
    и.т.д
]
```

Правильно ли выдавать ответ с именами столбцов . Такой ответ даёт понять потенциальному вредителю какие столбцы есть в нашей базе. Какие тут могут быть последствия? Нужно ли менять названия столбцов таблиц на другие?

Comment: Потенциальному вредителю абсолютно плевать, какие столбцы есть в вашей базе, если он всё равно не сможет получить доступ к вашей базе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобного рода безопасность стоит рассматривать в самую последнюю очередь. Важнее что вы пробрасываете структуру своей БД вплоть до слоя представления...То есть каждое маломальское изменение в структуре бд будет касаться UI части, хотите вы этого или нет. Другими словами процесс изменения внутренней структуры будет бесконтрольно влиять на представление(или другие системы, если вы с ними интегрируетесь по тем же принципам). А это тот еще "приз за лень".

Реальную проблему безопасности вы можете заработать если будете публиковать id объектов в виде лонгов...Вот это на самом деле раздолье на изучение вашего сайта на предмет дыр типа "а идет ли проверка, если я введу id не своей сущности которая уж наверняка автоинкремент (например форма редактирования сущности клиента, если он не должен был показаться вам по той или иной логике выборки клиентов, а вариантов этих выборок в зависимости от контекста может быть много больше чем одна)"

Ну и раз у вас есть такое желание, то скорей всего вы хотите пойти по пути анемичной модели. А там проблем безопасности и без этого хватит(везде проверять имеет ли пользователь доступ до данной сущности или ее "вложенной" подсущности)...

А вообще, если  у вас в проекте планируется больше 20 форм наделенных логикой чуть больше CRUD, очень рекомендую ознакомиться с практикой предметно ориентированного проектирования в связке с гексагональной архитектурой. Там вы по крайней мере будете контролировать все отношения в вашей системе.